# How to embed my website videos in facebook via status

Tags: video, youtube

I have a Joomla website having a lot of videos, I want to embed my videos in facebook by sharing via status update like you do when sharing youtube video. When you paste a link there facebook automatically extract the video and embed there. On my website I have videos but when I paste the link there on facebook it just treats it as a page not as a video. I want my videos to be playable there on facebook without redirecting to my website. Is there a way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This article should help you out: [Play Custom Video Player on Facebook](http://ahrengot.com/tutorials/custom-video-player-on-facebook/).

> Facebook and the Open Graph Protocol allows you to define special meta
>   data on your web pages that defines them in Facebook’s social graph.
>   In this post i’ll show you how to set up the meta tags required for
>   you to use a custom video player on Facebook, styled exactly like you
>   want it. It will show up, and play, directly within Facebook status
>   updates whenever someone shares the web page containing that meta
>   data. Pretty cool, huh?